# How can you execute a javascript function after another one is completed?

Tags: javascript, html, execute

I want that a javascript function executes after another one is completed. This is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});

window.addLoadEvent = function() {
$('#popuprel1').show();
}
```

Comment: define global var `isCompleted` and use it in every function or use `setTimeout()` in every function for a next function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the callback for fadeOut. It calls the second function once the initial animation is complete.

See http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Basically - you want to do something like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $('#popuprel1').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the second `onload` replaces the first one. Follow [this](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm).
For multiple events on `onload`, use `addLoadEvent`

Comment: You shouldn't call `addLoadEvent` like that. Pass your function as an argument: `window.addLoadEvent(function () { //code });`. Do that for every function you want to execute. They will be called in order, because `addLoadEvent` takes care of it. From the link: "The way this works is relatively simple: if window.onload has not already been assigned a function, the function passed to addLoadEvent is simply assigned to window.onload. If window.onload has already been set, a brand new function is created which first calls the original onload handler, then calls the new handler afterwards."

Comment: nope doesnt work, $(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
window.addLoadEvent(function () { $('#popuprel1').show(); }); doesnt still work

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? Do you want for `$('#popuprel1').show();` to execute after `#dvLoading` has faded out?